# Check if Targets exists with MSBuild task

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

Here is my code:

```
    <MSBuild Projects="outs.proj" Targets="Build;MyCustomTarget">
</MSBuild>
```

I need to check if MyCustomTarget exists in outs.proj before executing.

It throws an error when MyCustomTarget is not imported, so depending on the result use either Build or Build+MyCustomTarget.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a list of targets is cumbersome, you can either [reflect on `TaskHost` via `BuildEngine`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25363825/384478) to get current `Project` or re-evaluate the project with an inline task.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="Targets" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyName="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <Project ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <All ParameterType="System.String[]" Output="true" />
      <Run ParameterType="System.String[]" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build" />
      <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
      <Code>
        All = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(Project).Targets.Select(t => t.Key).ToArray();
        Run = Run.Where(All.Contains).ToArray();
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="Foo">
    <Targets Project="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Run="Foo;Baz">
      <Output TaskParameter="All" ItemName="All" />
      <Output TaskParameter="Run" ItemName="Run" />
    </Targets>
    <Message Text="All Targets: @(All)" />
    <Message Text="Run Targets: @(Run)" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Bar" />
</Project>
```

Edit:

You don't provide much details so I can't help with your particular issue, but if `new Project(Project)` throws may be try `ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject(Project)` instead to get to the `Targets`; the same collection has the `LoadedProjects` property as well as `GetLoadedProjects` and `UnloadProject` methods to play around with to get around your exception. If you're in control of the project file and it's flat with no `Import` you might want to try parsing it as a simple XML file rather than a fully fledged MSBuild project.

```
<XmlPeek XmlInputPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)" Query="/p:Project/p:Target/@Name" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='p' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' /&gt;">
  <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="All" />
</XmlPeek>
<ItemGroup>
  <In Include="Foo;Baz" />
  <Out Include="@(In)" Exclude="@(All)" />
  <Run Include="@(In)" Exclude="@(Out)" />
</ItemGroup>
<Message Text"@(Run)" />
```

In either case, you pass `outs.proj` path to whichever method you choose go with and get back `@(All)` with all of the targets in that project (`Foo;Bar`) then you filter your targets down from `Foo;Baz` to just `Foo` since `Baz` doesn't exit in `@(All)`. Then you do whatever you want to do with this information, e.g. `<MSBuild Projects="outs.proj" Targets="Build;@(Run)">`.

Comment: Sorry, my project is running inside Visual Studio, so I get the exception: project loaded, unload the project first. I'm also a little lost on how to apply the result to my MSBuild Projects="outs.proj" Targets="@(RunList)". How do I get RunList from outs.proj ?

Comment: I use ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection.LoadProject(Project), but XmlPeek tip was another solution to the problem: just need recursion for imported files. 2 answers in 1. Really great !